# Compiler does not recognize button

Tags: java, android

So I was attempting to create my first app after a long break, and found that something basic has slipped my knowledge, and for whatever reason, even the tutorials for it did not help. I created a button, but wanted it to be able to do things when clicked, so tried adding the code to `MainActivity`, though it caused error messages when I tried, wouldn't recognized "Button", "View", or "button_id", and I'm pretty much stumped. Below, I will include the `activity_main.xml` code, as well as the .java's code for reference.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:text="@string/button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now for the .java file.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Button` and `View` classes need to be imported; e.g.

```
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
```

Your class is in the default package, so all classes that it uses (apart from those in the `java.lang` package) need to be imported.

The reference to `button_id` is probably a mistake.

```
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);  // Delete this line
```

Alternatively, maybe you need to declare another button in your "activity_main.xml" file  whose id is `android:id="@+id/button_id"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, after following your advice, I was able to get it working! :)